# Firefox crashes immediately on start-up

Tags: firefox

I'm running a new install of Ubuntu 14.04 and my firefox crashes immediately upon starting up. Here is the error message I get in the terminal:

```
(firefox:6660): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:6660): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:6660): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:6660): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 6704
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I've tried purging and reinstalling firefox with apt-get but it didn't help. I also get a crash reporter, here are the contents of it:

```
Add-ons: ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.2,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:50.0.2,aushelper%40mozilla.org:1.0,webcompat%40mozilla.org:1.0,firefox%40getpocket.com:1.0.5,e10srollout%40mozilla.org:1.5,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:50.0.2,langpack-en-ZA%40firefox.mozilla.org:50.0.2
AddonsShouldHaveBlockedE10s: 1
BuildID: 20161130094553
ContentSandboxCapabilities: 117
CrashTime: 1481203588
E10SCohort: disqualified-test
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1481203057
Notes: OpenGL: Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2  -- 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 -- texture_from_pixmap
FP(D000-L10000-W00000000-T0000) 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 77
StartupTime: 1481203587
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20161130094553","version":"50.0.2","vendor":"Mozilla","platformVersion":"50.0.2","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","hotfixVersion":null},"partner":{"distributionId":null,"distributionVersion":null,"partnerId":null,"distributor":null,"distributorChannel":null,"partnerNames":[]},"system":{"memoryMB":15926,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":4,"cores":2,"vendor":"GenuineIntel","family":6,"model":142,"stepping":9,"l2cacheKB":256,"l3cacheKB":4096,"speedMHz":2701,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3","hasSSE4_1","hasSSE4_2","hasAVX","hasAVX2"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"4.4.0-53-generic","locale":"en-US"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"adapters":[{"description":"Intel Open Source Technology Center -- Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2 ","vendorID":"Intel Open Source Technology Center","deviceID":"Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2 ","subsysID":null,"RAM":null,"driver":null,"driverVersion":"3.0 Mesa 11.2.0","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[],"features":{"compositor":"none"}}},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":false,"e10sCohort":"disqualified-test","telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":true},"userPrefs":{"browser.newtabpage.enhanced":true},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":false},"profile":{}}
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
UptimeTS: .6687318
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 50.0.2
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone wants the fix for this same error, it got resolved when I upgraded my kernel to 4.8.14